# Print method name that you define with parameter

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, dev-c++

We are using a method

```
#define CM_VALUE_1                       CM_Method(3001)
```

CM_Method is a method define in same file .

I just want to print `CM_Method(3001)` by using `CM_VALUE_1` in vc++

Comment: Could you give an example of desired usage?

Comment: @abhi `#ifdef CM_VALUE_1 std::cout << "CM_METHOD(3001)" << std::endl; #endif`

Comment: Sorry,we con't print direct we have to print "CM_METHOD(3001)" by using CM_VALUE_1 this only

Comment: @abhi294074, Can you define it to be `"CM_Method(3001)"`? All you'd need is `std::cout << CM_VALUE_1;` A better way to do that would be not using macros at all, though.

Comment: Unfortunately the standard pre-processors that comes with compilers doesn't support replacing macros in strings. You can do it by running another pre-processor (like [filepp](http://www.cabaret.demon.co.uk/filepp/)) which does replacements in strings first.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Really? I got nothing from GCC 4.7.0.

Comment: @Chris CM_Method(3001) is a method that return a integer value,so if we do like "std::cout << CM_VALUE_1" then we get that retun value not the method name with parameter like CM_Method(3001)

Comment: you've asked 7 questions and not accepted one single answer. Don't you like being helped?

Answer (score 5):

Use the stringize preprocessor operator indirectly to get what you want.

```
#define MAKE_STR(X) #X
#define MAKE_STR2(X) MAKE_STR(X)

std::cout << MAKE_STR(CM_VALUE_1)
          << " is " << MAKE_STR2(CM_VALUE_1)
          << std::endl;
```

will result in

```
CM_VALUE_1 is CM_METHOD(3001)
```

If the parameter to `MAKE_STR2` is itself a macro, it is expanded when calling `MAKE_STR`, so the outcome is the stringization of what the parameter was defined to be, rather than the macro name itself.